# Replace characters with carriage return - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, replace, carriage-return

I would like to ask for help in learning how to replace a 3 different combinations of characters from a string, and replace them with a carriage return.

The character combinations are:

```
++~
~~+
+~\
```

I would like to be able to replace those combinations with a carriage return.

String example:

```
Capacity for the concerts is 3,645 persons with additional safety conditions.++~ Approved contractor will barricade and cone the race route.++~ Coordinate activities and schedule with the street coordinator, 608-261-9171.++~ Animals must remain in fenced area ~~+ Maintain access to Metro stops.~~+ There is no event parking in the parking lot.~~+ Event volunteers and staff will monitor the barricades during the event.~~+ Staff will review the event for compliance to the established conditions and determine what remediation (if any) is needed and/or establish considerations for future events.+~\ Event organizer/sponsor is responsible for cleanup of event area. Charges will be assessed for any staff time or resources required for clean-up.+~\
```

Any help with code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

UPDATE

I have a starter function, it does the work, but I am not sure if this is an extensible solution.

```
function findAndReplace() {

    var string = 'Addendum and/or contract providing additional event details and conditions. Capacity for the King St. concerts is 3,645 persons with additional safety conditions as per Addendum.++~ Addendum and/or contract providing additional event details and conditions on file in Madison Parks.++~ Notification: Event participants must be notified prior to the race that they must adhere to the traffic signals. They are not allowed to stop traffic during the event.++~ Organizer must notify hotels, businesses and residents along the approved bike route. Include estimated time periods when athletics will "block" access and provide day-off contact information.++~ Call the Sayle Street Garage, 608-266-4767, 1120 Sayle St, to make arrangements to pick up and return barricades required for event. There may be charges for this equipment.++~ '; 

    var target1 = '++~ ';   
    var target2 = '~~+ ';   
    var target3 = '+~\\ ';  

    var replacement = '\n';

    var i = 0, length = string.length;

    for (i; i < length; i++) { 

        string = string.replace(target1, replacement) 
                        .replace(target2, replacement)
                        .replace(target3, replacement);
    }

    return string;

} 

console.log(findAndReplace());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple regex will replace all occurance in the string.

```
/\+\+~|~~\+|\+~\\/g
```

You first need to escape the `\` in the string so this `abc+~\monkey` would become this `abc+~\\monkey`.

Then you can use split to split the items. map to do some cleanup on the items, then join to insert your carriage return `\r\n`

```js
let str = 'Capacity for the concerts is 3,645 persons with additional safety conditions.++~ Approved contractor will barricade and cone the race route.++~ Coordinate activities and schedule with the street coordinator, 608-261-9171.++~ Animals must remain in fenced area ~~+ Maintain access to Metro stops.~~+ There is no event parking in the parking lot.~~+ Event volunteers and staff will monitor the barricades during the event.~~+ Staff will review the event for compliance to the established conditions and determine what remediation (if any) is needed and/or establish considerations for future events.+~\\ Event organizer/sponsor is responsible for cleanup of event area. Charges will be assessed for any staff time or resources required for clean-up.+~\\'

str = str.split(/\+\+~|~~\+|\+~\\/g).map(i => i.trim()).join('\r\n')

console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use the replace function in js:-

```js
let sampleStr = `Capacity for the concerts is 3,645 persons with additional safety conditions.++~ Approved contractor will barricade and cone the race route.++~ Coordinate activities and schedule with the street coordinator, 608-261-9171.++~ Animals must remain in fenced area ~~+ Maintain access to Metro stops.~~+ There is no event parking in the parking lot.~~+ Event volunteers and staff will monitor the barricades during the event.~~+ Staff will review the event for compliance to the established conditions and determine what remediation (if any) is needed and/or establish considerations for future events.+~\ Event organizer/sponsor is responsible for cleanup of event area. Charges will be assessed for any staff time or resources required for clean-up.+~\ `;

let replacedString  = sampleStr.replace(/\++~/g, '\r').replace(/~~\+/g,'\r').replace(/\+~\\/g,'\r');

alert(replacedString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
const str = "Capacity for the concerts is 3,645 persons with additional safety conditions.++~ Approved contractor will barricade and cone the race route.++~ Coordinate activities and schedule with the street coordinator, 608-261-9171.++~ Animals must remain in fenced area ~~+ Maintain access to Metro stops.~~+ There is no event parking in the parking lot.~~+ Event volunteers and staff will monitor the barricades during the event.~~+ Staff will review the event for compliance to the established conditions and determine what remediation (if any) is needed and/or establish considerations for future events.+~\\ Event organizer/sponsor is responsible for cleanup of event area. Charges will be assessed for any staff time or resources required for clean-up.+~\\  ";

console.log(str.replace(/\+\+~|~~\+|\+~\\/g, '<new symbol>'));
```